# Creating a sub type with only part of the original types properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript definitions:

```
interface myType {
    A: {
      instance: someInstance,
      ...
    },
    B: {
      instance: someOtherInstance,
      ...
    }
}
```

I would like to create a type, that takes all of the properties of the `myType` interface, and produces an object, that accepts the type of the instance from that interface. Something along the lines of these:

```
type myBasicType<TType> = '...';

const a: myBasicType<myType> = {
   A: '...', // an instance of someInstance here
   B: '...', // an instance of someOtherInstance here
}
```

Basically, what I need is a functionality, that generates a type based on an interface, where the properties of the original interface are kept intact, but their types are changed to a new type based on a specific property from the original interface.

Comment: Why don't just use `const a: myType = {  }`?

Comment: @Nick because I do not need the additional nested data from there. In my variable, I need the A property to be something of the `someInstance` type, instead of it being an object, that contains an `instance` property with something of the `someInstace` type.

Comment: You mean a _mapped type_: https://tsplay.dev/mAVBZW

Comment: This is impossible. If it doesn't have all the properties of the super type, then it is *by definition* not a sub type, and if it is a sub type, then it must have all properties of the super type. A sub type that has only some of the properties of the super type is a logical contradiction.

Comment: @JorgWMittag I need a sub type that has all of the properties of the super type, but with different type associated to those properties, based on a property of the super types property types. The accepted answer does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
class someInstance {
  tag: 'someInstance' = 'someInstance'
}

class someOtherInstance {
  tag: 'someOtherInstance' = 'someOtherInstance'
}

interface myType {
  A: {
    instance: someInstance,
  },
  B: {
    instance: someOtherInstance,
  }
}

type Mapper<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends { instance: unknown } ? T[Prop]['instance'] : never
}

// type Result = {
//     A: someInstance;
//     B: someOtherInstance;
// }
type Result = Mapper<myType>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEEPYFsCmBJAdhALmNwnQG8AoaabAcwC5oByeZdLHPG6AXlvtQ21yRqIBfIkVCQYXAPKYAFkgBOjXnkIkyYKp0RJpcxT2b92W5LoVLDA4UQCWaTAoBmYFQgCeAFTcAHfMVIAgtT%20pNB2THzUXBZ8ADRqgvGkAELBaqThykhR2mb6EXhJ0MLWmD74ALJg3r7yADweAHzGIQDaAArycN5haNAA1khucI7QHgC61B4dXd7j0EgAHg5oACYwBL0F2dAArmj9aHAA7n2C0AD8YzPd4600mZbz1GhIAG4KQiIA9N9k5dAAEpICC7ECYFpEX6hQI5BgGPgAbihfxhqVguVk5gReGR0OEZV8QJBYIhHCqNQUdXcXl8jSAA)